# Stopping Vim from opening all subsequent closed folds when creating a new one

Tags: vim, folding

I noticed that when I create a new fold (I'm using `foldmethod=marker`), all the folds below the one I'm creating are automatically opened. Is there a way to prevent this and leave them closed?

I can't use `zf` to manually create a fold because I'm editing a PHP/HTML file, and there is no `'commentstring'` format good for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating the `}}}` end marker *before* creating the `{{{` start
marker. This should prevent Vim from getting confused and opening the
following folds.

Also, if you find you accidentally open some folds, just reload the
file for editing with the `:e` command to reset them.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible not only by creating the closing marker before the
opening one, but also by specifying the fold level in markers.

```
{{{1
    Fold you are closing.
    Inserting the closing marker below would not open the next fold.
}}}

{{{1
    Closed fold.
}}}
```

In this case, the fold levels helps Vim to find matching closing
marker and not try one that closes the next fold.

Comment: Seems to make no difference, as soon as I insert the closing marker, all other folds below are open

Comment: Are levels specified for those folds (next to one you are closing) too?

Comment: That's why Vim still tries to open them to find matching markers.  Appending level numbers to the markers solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than typing out the marks by hand, I tend to visually mark the reigon I want to fold with `V` then use `zf` to create the fold.

This does not open any folds that aren't open already.

Comment: This would be good but I need to fold both PHP and HTML code, so I can't have a single `'commentstring'`

Comment: Might want to edit your question to include that information so people don't have to read all the comments to find it.